# How to copy contents of a directory to another location in Android

Tags: java, android, copy

I want to copy contents from one location to another.
I tried few of the methods, but I am interested in a faster approach for copying of the files.

I have few constraints,
I cannot use org.apache.commons.io package or use exec call for cp -r

Is there any android utility method or a simple faster program for doing the same.
I tried the below code, but it seems slower.

```
public static void copyDirectory(String sourceDirectoryLocation, String destinationDirectoryLocation) 
      throws IOException {
        Files.walk(Paths.get(sourceDirectoryLocation))
          .forEach(source -> {
              Path destination = Paths.get(destinationDirectoryLocation, source.toString()
                .substring(sourceDirectoryLocation.length()));
              try {
                  Files.copy(source, destination);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you show us what did you try? Or else visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question

Comment: What is Files class?

Comment: These are from java.nio package

Comment: There is no faster method. Processing depends upon your storage speed (UHS 2.0 or UHS 3.0) and your processing power.